# How to have multiple state files for a workspace in terraform gcs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-storage

In AWS, when i set the backend provider to be S3, I'm able to set multiple keys.
I can have one key for the database, another key for the cluster, etc.

```
key - (Required) Path to the state file inside the S3 Bucket. When using a non-default workspace, the state path will be /workspace_key_prefix/workspace_name/key (see also the workspace_key_prefix configuration).
```

Then in a module like my kube deployments, I can grab the remote state and use the cluster, separate from the DB, etc.

The GCS backend does not seem to support key.
`https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/gcs`
It seems to dump everything in your workspace name like myworkspace.tfstate.

So when I go from one module to another, say from DB to Network, applying the terraform config, it will nuke everything from DB when I apply in network and vice versa in DB from network.

When I get to my deployments, I'm able to grab all the remote state by each key name so I'd have

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "network" {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    bucket = local.tf-state-bucket-name
    key    = "workspaces/${terraform.workspace}/terraform-network.tfstate"
    region = "us-west-1"
  }
}
```

and

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "rds" {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    bucket = local.tf-state-bucket-name
    key    = "workspaces/${terraform.workspace}/terraform-rds.tfstate"
    region = "us-west-1"
  }
}
```

I could then grab the DB username like so
`data.terraform_remote_state.rds.outputs.db_username`

I keep trying to implement my GCP setup DB/VPC/Network/GKE to look just like my AWS setup, but it just doesn't seem supported.

It seems that the key will always be the name of the workspace?

Would I instead of having in S3 a path like
`workspaces/my-workspace/db.tfstate`

in GCS, would i do like
`db/my-workspace.tfstate`

Comment: How about https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/gcs#prefix?

Comment: right, so i'm assuming the prefix for the DB module would be `db` and the prefix for vpc would be `vpc`. I was just confused because with s3 i'd name my key `db` and `vpc`... It was `workspaces/workspace-id/db.tfstate` and now i guess it would be `db/workspace-id.tfstate`